# How do I create a CGlayer that has an image drawn to it?

Tags: iphone, cglayer

I just need to know hot to create a `CGLayer` that has an image drawn to it. I am not completely understanding the documentation entirely. Thanks

Comment: For basic info on CGlayer, this may well help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458812/whats-the-difference-and-compatibility-of-cglayer-and-calayer/4594394#4594394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I posted a blog post on a similar topic, available here:

[Drawing UIImages right side up using CoreGraphics](http://davedelong.com/blog/2009/03/13/drawing-uiimages-right-side-using-coregraphics)

In that post, I show how to draw a UIImage so that's it's grayscale.  Part of that includes creating a new layer with a gray colorspace (so it draws in shades of gray), and then extracting the `CGContextRef` from the `CGLayer`, pushing it to the context stack, drawing the `UIImage`, and then popping the context stack.  The `UIImage` draws onto the topmost `CGContextRef`, which will be the context that corresponds to your `CGLayer`.

There are probably other ways to do this, but this is how I've done it in the past, and it's always worked great for me.

Comment: When changing the .image property of an UIImageView, do you know if the system is using CGLayer to get good performance ? Or do I need to use your code to get a better FPS ?

Comment: @Cedric it's getting passed through to the underlying `CALayer`, so it's not going through a `CGLayer` at all.